# Is there similarity between Promise and DataFlow?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, dataflow

As far as I know promise returns future and dataflow also return future and I believe dataflow is abstraction on promise and is triggers when the values it depends on become available. Is dataflow like a graph structure of promise?. Can anyone shed light on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can think of dataflow as a graph of futures. So this dataflow graph:

[image]

Can be implemented with futures (in Clojure) like this:

```
user=> (let [a (future (+ 1 2))
  #_=>       b (future (+ 3 4))]
  #_=>   (+ @a @b))
10
```

(this example comes from [Seven Concurrency Models in Seven Weeks](http://pragprog.com/book/pb7con/seven-concurrency-models-in-seven-weeks)).

Having said that, although there are conceptual similarities between the two, futures are rarely used to implement pure dataflow, because they're typically too expensive (certainly too expensive to use with simple addition operations like this).

If you're interested in dataflow in particular, you might like to take a look at the [Oz language](http://mozart.github.io). Another approach that has conceptual similarities is Reactive Programming using, for example, Microsoft's [Rx (Reactive Extensions)](https://rx.codeplex.com) library.

Comment: - Thank you for the answer. When you say graph of  futures are expensive it makes sense. So why not create graph of promise? Isn't that better ?

Comment: You could use promises instead, but the cost of a promise is very little different from the cost of a future. The bottom line is that nobody has succeeded in getting dataflow working convincingly well for tiny operations like addition (outside of hardware languages like Verilog and VHDL, that is).

Comment: you have made things clearer. I just wanted to make these things sure whether I was in right direction or not.